# How to get rid of irrelevant results (similar words to that in query) in Windows search

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

Windows 10's (or my copy of Windows 10's) search tool in File Explorer works in this odd way where results include filenames with not only the query I use, but also those with similar words. For example, searching for "karma" returns files that have "kar", "kara", "karin" etc. in their names.

The only way to get the relevant results is to search for the query in quotes (and even that doesn't work all the time); which prevents me from using wildcards on the query.

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds to get rid of this behaviour?